# discord.py version 1.3.4 dont know how to make the bot play a mp3 in a vc

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a chatbot with chatterbot and that works well but I wanted to make it do text to speech. Got the whole tts thing working with gtts.  I went through looking if anyone else wanted to do something similar and I couldn't find anything.  If it's possible could you also show how to make a join leave command as I'm new to discord.py and the documentation is not fun to read.
don't know how long hastebin lasts but https://hasteb.in/rutasexo.py

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/978
this was useful and the code to make the bot play the mp3 is

```
    voice = await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="where your FFmpeg is installed, make sure you put the ffmpeg.exe", source='response.mp3'))
```